# How to prove such equation $ f^{-1} (\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i) = \bigcap_{i\in I} f^{-1}(A_i)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am not able to prove this equation, not sure where to start from.

Comment: Start with $x\in f^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\right)$ and aim to infer $x\in\bigcap_{i\in I}f^{-1}(A_i)$. And then do it the other way round.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Which is to say, the completely standard, 98% of the time approach to proving that two sets are equal.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Let $x\in f^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\right)$ then try to show that $x\in \bigcap_{i\in I}f^{-1}(A_i)$. Then go the other way around.

**Further Hint:**
Let $x\in f^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\right)$ then there exists a $y\in \bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$ such that $f(x) = y$. Then $y\in A_i$ for every $i\in I$ and $x\in f^{-1}(A_i)$ so $x\in \bigcap_{i\in I}f^{-1}(A_i)$. Now go the other way around.

Let me know if you need a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

Show that:

1) $f^{-1}(\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i) \subset \bigcap_{i \in I} f^{-1}(A_i)$;

$b \in f^{-1}(\bigcap_{i  \in I} A_i)$, there is an

$a \in \bigcap_{i  \in I} A_i$, s.t. $b= f^{-1}(a)$.

Then $a \in A_i$, for $i \in I$, i .e.

$b \in f^{-1}(A_i)$ , for $i \in I$.

Hence $b \in \bigcap_{i \in I} f^{-1}(A_i)$.